# angular ui.mask for variable length format

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

i am trying to use angular ui.mask module to display a full length url based on user entering a section name(suffix)

http://www.example.com/XYZ where 'XYZ' is the user input.

While a mask 'http://www.example.com/AAA' works fine, it does limit the user to entering only 3 character. 
Any quick ways to extend the length accepted?

I tried altering the regex to accept variable length, but haven't got this working.
Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: The `ui.mask` module was designed to work with inputs that require a pre-defined length. I don't see a way of using it to do what you need.

Comment: ui.mask usage was an overkill anyways for the simple concatenated display that i needed in my case. ( what was i thinking ! )
i added span and just displayed the concatenated string.

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished by using a question mark before any character in the mask that would be optional.

In your case, it would look like:

```
ui-mask='http://www.example.com/?A?A?A?A?A?A?A?A?A?A?A?A?A?A?A?A'
```

Better late than never...